# Easy way to perform solver over pandas dataframe

Tags: optimization, python, nonlinear-equations, scipy

I'm moving from Excel to Python and I'm trying to solve these equations:

$$\begin{align}
X_1&=\bigg[\big(3.47-\log(X_2)\big)^2+\big(\log(c)+1.22)^2\bigg]^{0.5}\\
X_2&=\frac{a}{101.32}\bigg(\frac{101.32}{b}\bigg)^{X_3}\\
X_3&=0.381X_1+0.05\bigg(\frac{b}{101.32}\bigg)-0.15
\end{align}
$$
I have tried this code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.optimize as opt
from scipy.optimize import NonlinearConstraint
np.random.seed(42)
a = np.linspace(300,400,30) 
b = np.random.randint(700,18000,30) 
c = np.random.uniform(1.4,4.0,30) 
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':a, 'B':b, 'C':c})


def func(zGuess,*Params):
    x,y,z = zGuess
    a,b,c = Params
    
    eq_1 = (((3.47-np.log10(y))**2+(np.log10(c)+1.22)**2)**0.5) - x
    eq_2 = ((a/101.32) * (101.32/b)** z) - y
    eq_3 = (0.381 * x + 0.05 * (b/101.32) -0.15) - z
    return eq_1,eq_2,eq_3


zGuess = np.array([2.6,20.2,0.92])
df['x'],df['y'],df['z'] = zip(*df.apply(lambda x: opt.fsolve(func,zGuess,args=(x['A'],x['B'],x['C'])),1) )
```

but it returns the first guess as solution.

In Excel I would run a VBA:

```vba
Sub Solver_n()
'
' Macro6 Macro
'

'
'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For l = 3 To 32

    SolverOk SetCell:=Cells(l, 14), MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Cells(l, 12), Engine:=1 _
        , EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:=Cells(l, 14), MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Cells(l, 12), Engine:=1 _
        , EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve (True)
outro:
Next l
'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

where `(l,14)` is the residual
and `(l,12)` is the n_calc
and would give the correct solution as presented [here](https://github.com/jc-barreto/Some_tests/blob/main/test_df.xlsm).

I trust the excel solution because it has a physical meaning and it is what I expect, but the Python solution does not match. How can resolve this problem in Python?

I would like to move to Python because it is easier to deal with plotting and large datasets as Pandas dataframes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `y` gets values close to zero so the solver steps over the axis and tries negative values during the derivative computation via difference quotients. This does not work with `log10`.

You can

- replace `log10(y)` with the cut-off version `0.5*log10(1e-8+y*y)`. This gives solution, you would have to check how good they are relative to the original equations.
- replace `y` with `10**v`, so that `log10(y)` is replaced with `v` and  the second equation with

```
eq2 = (np.log10(a/101.32) -np.log10(101.32/b)*z) - v
```

You would have to translate the initial value of `y` with the one for `v` and the solution back,...

- just iterate the given equations as fixed-point iteration. This might not converge, or not converge fast, but has no numerical singularities.

Some solvers also allow to set boundaries, so that negative values in `y` can be directly avoided.

Comment: Thank you! this answer helped me to understand better my problem!